# Compiler error for exhaustive switch

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

Why do I get a "*not all code paths return a value*", for `VeryBoolToBool()` in the following code?

```
public enum VeryBool { VeryTrue, VeryFalse };
public bool VeryBoolToBool(VeryBool veryBool)
{
    switch(veryBool)
    {
        case VeryBool.VeryTrue:
            return true;

        case VeryBool.VeryFalse:
            return false;

        // Un-commenting the unreachable(?) default clause will solve this
        // default:
        //    throw new HowTheHellDidIGetHereException();
    }
}
```

Can't the compiler see there are no other options for `VeryBool`?

Comment: `VeryBool val = (VeryBool)42;` is perfectly legitimate. Your switch is not exhaustive.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can't the compiler see there are no other options for VeryBool?

Nope, because there are. For example, I could call:

```
VeryBoolToBool((VeryBool) 5);
```

Enums in C# are *not* limited sets of values. They're effectively named numbers, with additional compile-time type safety in that there aren't implicit conversions between enums or between enums and numbers. (There are explicit conversions though.) The explicit conversions do *not* ensure that the value in question is one with a name, however.

Beyond that, `switch` in C# never checks whether all possible values of the type are explicitly listed. The end of a switch statement is always deemed "reachable" unless there's a `default` case (and all cases terminate). More precisely, from the end of section 8.7.2 of the C# 5 specification:

> The end point of a switch statement is reachable if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The switch statement contains a reachable break statement that exits the switch statement.
> - The switch statement is reachable, the switch expression is a non-constant value, and no default label is present.
> - The switch statement is reachable, the switch expression is a constant value that doesn’t match any case label, and no default label is present.

Comment: Hmm. 
I was wondering if this choice was aimed to ease the implementation of enums in .Net, or is there some benefit in doing stuff like Marc's `VeryBool val = (VeryBool)42;`?

Comment: @bavaza: There are times when it's useful for enums to behave like this - but plenty of others where it's not. I wish there were a "strict enum" type in .NET, but for the moment we need to live with what we've got :(

Comment: The most common case where you would want this behavior is when your `bool` is being used as a bit field (for flags).  If you used code [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8462/18192), you could then use `MyEnum foo = MyEnum.First | MyEnum.Second`.

Comment: This is true for Enums, but not for Disjoint Union Implemented via marker interface and inherited types. It would be nice if the compiler actually performed an exhaustive check, but I suppose with various dynamic assembly loading malarky you could always end up with an extra type at runtime. Oh C# how you tease

Answer (score 2):

Since C# 8 you can use a switch expression to solve this:

```cs
public enum VeryBool { VeryTrue, VeryFalse };

public bool VeryBoolToBool(VeryBool veryBool)
{
    return veryBool switch
    {
        VeryBool.VeryTrue => true,
        VeryBool.VeryFalse => false
    };
}
```

Note that you will get a warning:

```
The switch expression does not handle some values of its input type (it is not exhaustive) involving an unnamed enum value. For example, the pattern '(Fruit)2' is not covered.
```

But the warning can be suppressed or configured in your editor config (CS8524).

You can still pass an invalid enum value:

```cs
VeryBoolToBool((VeryBool) 5);
```

But this will throw a SwitchExpressionException.